# Bluetooth Low Energy : Android Gatt-Client connect to Linux Gatt Server

Tags: linux, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluez

I try to connect android to linux via bluetooth low energy GATT mode.

There is a example code in Bluez: [btgatt-server.c](http://code.metager.de/source/xref/linux/bluetooth/bluez/tools/btgatt-server.c?r=61a4a47df67fcc8fd71d1acda28ee2b28219ffa0), I use it as server.

The Android Side be as the [Android official example:Connecting to a GATT Server](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html). That is, use function BluetoothDevice::connectGatt(Context context, boolean autoConnect, BluetoothGattCallback callback).

After running, the Android part returned the connection be successful,(the parameter of BluetoothGattCallback::onConnectionStateChange be STATE_CONNECTED), but the program in linux(btgatt-server) did not get any response, that still block in waiting accepting.
( line 485).

I also used another example code : [l2cap-ble.c](https://github.com/sandeepmistry/noble/blob/master/src/l2cap-ble.c), the result was totally the same.

Anyone could help me? my goal is : after connecting, linux gatt server would send a data to Android. Then disconnecting.

thank you lots.

Comment: what happen when you try discovering services from your Android app? Also try `btmon` to see if any packet exchange is really happening through your bluetooth interface.

Comment: In my [blogger](http://gaiger-programming.blogspot.tw/2015/01/bluetooth-low-energy-customizing-gatt.html), I have done the issue to customize gatt service, please refer to it.

Answer (score 2):

I just now faced the same problems.

This seems like a bug that happens with Android and Broadcom bluetooth modules. Android somehow connects to the wrong l2cap channel.

A workaround is to **explicitely disable BR/EDR** support in the advertisements.

The bug report on google with the solution in #8 can be found [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58896#c8), the quote on the hint that helped me:

> I have obtained information from Broadcom regarding this bug and I don't think its a bug on their part. If one does not specifically set the 'BR/EDR not supported' bit in the advertisement (bit 2), the Broadcom stack will use BR/EDR and BTLE.
>   Changing the leading advertisement package from 020102 to 020106 solved the problem.

Using bluez *btmgmt* for configuring the advertisements on device hci0 i issue the following commands:

```
btmgmt -i hci0 power off 
btmgmt -i hci0 le on
btmgmt -i hci0 connectable on
btmgmt -i hci0 bredr off        # Disables BR/EDR !
btmgmt -i hci0 advertising on
btmgmt -i hci0 power on
```

Starting the bluez btgatt-server example:

```
btgatt-server -i hci0 -s low -t public -r -v
```

Comment: And if you want to used Bluetooth classic and BLE on your device how do you do? Because BREDR off is disabling the BTC support.

Comment: I don't think this is possible with a single adapter.

Comment: We are currently using our custom embedded device with BTC and BLE. It is working perfectly. We are using Broadcom hardware also. Of course the mobile application need to choose if she want to use BLE or BTC connexion. But both are possible in embedded device side. Device is always waiting for BTC or BLE connexion.

Comment: It seems possible if hardware supports it, see [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/258836/bluetooth-dual-mode-br-edr-le) stackexchange thread. I dont know how to configure and use it with bluez.