# Android's BLE Service Discovery (BluetoothGatt#discoverServices()) and Low Energy vs BR/EDR

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth

**TLDR: Is it expected that service discovery results via [`discoverServices()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#discoverServices()) will differ based on the underlying transport (LE vs. BR/EDR)?**

I have a mixed-mode Bluetooth accessory that offers distinct features as a Bluetooth Classic device and as a Bluetooth LE Peripheral.

Android has trouble discovering the accessory's Bluetooth LE GATT services unless you use the hidden [`peerBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, autoConnect, gattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r4/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java#1424) API that allows you to force use of either `TRANSPORT_LE` or `TRANSPORT_BREDR`.

When I connected the device via [`peerBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, autoConnect, gattCallback)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r4/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java#1403) and then called [`discoverServices()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.html#discoverServices()) I'd only discover the generic Service UUIDs (and only after many failed connection attempts with mysterious status 133 delivered to [`onConnectionStateChange`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r4/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCallback.java#35)).

- “00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb” (Generic Access)
- “00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb” (Generic Attribute).

However, when I invoke the hidden [`peerBluetoothDevice.connectGatt(context, autoConnect, gattCallback, BluetoothDevice.TRANSPORT_LE)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-5.1.1_r4/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.java#1424) and then called `discoverServices()` I get the full expected service discovery response:

- "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" (My custom service)
- “00001800-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb” (Generic Access)
- “00001801-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb” (Generic Attribute).

Is this expected Android framework behavior (Doubt it, hence hidden API)? Is it bad form to design a peripheral device with this 'mixed mode' operation?

Comment: If i remember correctly, when your Beacon advertizes BR/EDR support, android defaults to use it, which results in errors. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/31369286/3623345 and the corresponding thread. If this is WAI, or if there is at least a good reasson to do so, i dont know.

Comment: Sorry, i linked the wrong post. In http://stackoverflow.com/a/31148924/3623345 is also a link to a google bug report about this issue (https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58896) dating back to 2013 still being listed as "New"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The

[`BluetoothDevice.connectGatt(Context context, boolean autoConnect, android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback callback, int transport)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothDevice.html)

method is public as of API 23, and so seems to be the sanctioned way of avoiding the problem described above.

The method appears to have been [introduced](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/commit/b88fa824ab6337684de9aa8437c4952df4f1a75e/) to AOSP in the `android-5.0.0_r1` release, and  was present in every release leading up to it being made public in API 23.
Therefore, it should be safe to invoke via reflection for devices with API levels 21 and 22. For devices with prior platform versions, it appears the Android framework does not provide tools to mitigate the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have a Xamarin application needs to connect to a dual mode Bluetooth device (Classic & BLE) over the BLE connection. When use  [ConnectGatt(Context, Boolean, BluetoothGattCallback)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.connectgatt?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12#android-bluetooth-bluetoothdevice-connectgatt(android-content-context-system-boolean-android-bluetooth-bluetoothgattcallback)), the gatt.GetService(UUID) always returns null in the OnServicesDiscovered() callback. After switching to [ConnectGatt(Context, Boolean, BluetoothGattCallback, BluetoothTransports)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/android.bluetooth.bluetoothdevice.connectgatt?view=xamarin-android-sdk-12#android-bluetooth-bluetoothdevice-connectgatt(android-content-context-system-boolean-android-bluetooth-bluetoothgattcallback-android-bluetooth-bluetoothtransports)) with the BluetoothTransports.Le for the transports parameter, the GetService(UUID) returns with the custom service successfully every time. This works perfectly for BLE in a dual mode situation.