# Bluetooth low energy bluez example server and connectGatt fail

Tags: android, linux, kernel, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

I have this problem since one week now and im feeling like im missing something very obvious but i cant really pin it down. Im having a ble peripheral which works with an app im using. Im currently attempting to rebuild the peripheral (the services and characteristics) using the raspberry pi and the example gatt server from inside the bluez source (test/example-gattserver). The app and the peripheral work fine but when i try to connect it to my pi it doesnt. The example gatt server works very nice with apps like Nrf connect and im able to connect to the server and read the services and characteristics. The app works that way: if the peripheral is already bonded remove the bond and create a new one. Afterwards connectGatt gets called. When i try to use my raspberry pi as the peripheral it always gets the STATE_DISCONNECTED which is when we are looking at the hci dump correct. I attached the hcidump below in hope someone is able to read more out of it then i am.

Things i tried already:

This seemed like a very similar problem: https://github.com/noble/noble/issues/242
so i removed the changes of https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux.git/commit/net/bluetooth?id=0fe29fd1cd77ffbdb8e36ec1715868d9d8011c9b and rebuild the kernel but nothing changed in the behaviour.

[Bluetooth Low Energy : Android Gatt-Client connect to Linux Gatt Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27552644/bluetooth-low-energy-android-gatt-client-connect-to-linux-gatt-server) I disabled BR/EDR but then i wasnt able to connect and pair to the raspberry pi at all.

hcidump:
https://pastebin.com/nrt3Fuy0

The part where it disconnects/gets disconnected:

```
< ACL data: handle 15 flags 0x00 dlen 12
    L2CAP(s): Disconn req: dcid 0x0047 scid 0x0040
> ACL data: handle 15 flags 0x02 dlen 12
    L2CAP(s): Disconn rsp: dcid 0x0047 scid 0x0040
> HCI Event: Number of Completed Packets (0x13) plen 5
    handle 15 packets 1
< HCI Command: Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) plen 3
    handle 15 reason 0x13
    Reason: Remote User Terminated Connection
> HCI Event: Command Status (0x0f) plen 4
    Disconnect (0x01|0x0006) status 0x00 ncmd 1
> HCI Event: Disconn Complete (0x05) plen 4
    status 0x00 handle 15 reason 0x16
    Reason: Connection Terminated by Local Host
```

This is my first question on stackoverflow as im most of the times finding the solutions, but this time i didnt. In case i made anything wrong with this submission, write a comment please and i will fix it as soon as possible.

Comment: This may help: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/61758/does-rpi-3-have-ble-bluetooth-low-energy-bluetooth-4-0-bluetooth-smart